# How to parse a single column of a table?

Tags: jsoup

i am a beginner in android programming.I am developing an app which uses jsoup to parse HTML table data from a website.The problem which i am facing is, the table does not have an id and all table data  has the same class name.How can i pick the data from a single column? I only want the table data from the second column

Here is the HTML :

```
<table  width=100% border=0 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1>

  <tr class="rowdeep">

    <td align="center" class="bodytext"><strong>Train No</strong></td>
    <td align="center" class="bodytext"><strong>Name</strong></td>
    <td align="center" class="bodytext"><strong>Off Day</strong></td>
    <td align="center" class="bodytext"><strong>From</strong></td>
    <td align="center" class="bodytext"><strong>Departure</strong></td>
    <td align="center" class="bodytext"><strong>To</strong></td>
    <td align="center" class="bodytext"><strong>Arrival</strong></td>

  </tr>

  <tr class="rowlight">

    <td align="center" class="bodytext">773</td>
    <td align="center" class="bodytext">Kalani Express</td>
    <td align="center" class="bodytext">Friday</td>
    <td align="center" class="bodytext">Dhaka</td>
    <td align="center" class="bodytext">4:00:00 PM</td>
    <td align="center" class="bodytext">Sylhet</td>
    <td align="center" class="bodytext">10:45:00 PM</td>

  </tr>

  <tr class="rowlight">
    <td align="center" class="bodytext">707</td>
    <td align="center" class="bodytext">Tista Express</td>
    <td align="center" class="bodytext">Monday</td>
    <td align="center" class="bodytext">Dhaka</td>
    <td align="center" class="bodytext">7:20:00 AM</td>
    <td align="center" class="bodytext">Dewangonge Bazar</td>
    <td align="center" class="bodytext">12:55:00 PM</td>
 </tr>

<table>
```

Comment: Have you solved this yet? Please accept the answer if it solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

So assuming you have parsed the HTML into a Document already, this should work:

```
Elements tableRows = doc.select("tr.rowdeep, tr.rowlight");

for (Element e : tableRows) {
    System.out.println(e.child(1).text()); // index of 2nd column
}
```

Will output:

```
Name
Kalani Express
Tista Express
```